# Command Line Windows. How to view whole response after applying instructions

Tags: windows, windows-8, console

I am trying to run some commands using the console in windows 8. My problem is that I have a hard time debugging an application I build, as the response I get after some commands is **too big**. I have maximized the window but I can only view some lines (50-60 does not matter).

How can I view everything from the beginning to the end?

Comment: You can direct the ouput of running your command to a text file, which you can then open in the editor of your choice. So you'd do 'yourcommand > filename.txt'

Comment: You could try to increase the buffer size of the console or redirect output.